# how i can install project laravel like irwanmohi/softether-panel

Tags: laravel

how i can install project Laravel Like this
https://github.com/irwanmohi/softether-panel

after extract this script in xammp and run
i see this error

Warning: require(D:\xampp\htdocs\softether\public/../vendor/autoload.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\xampp\htdocs\softether\public\index.php on line 24

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Failed opening required 'D:\xampp\htdocs\softether\public/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='D:\xampp\php\PEAR') in D:\xampp\htdocs\softether\public\index.php:24 Stack trace: #0 D:\xampp\htdocs\softether\server.php(21): require_once() #1 {main} thrown in D:\xampp\htdocs\softether\public\index.php on line 24

vendor/autoload.php this path and file not exist in script

how can fix this and run script ?

also i set .env database and domain for script after run i see fatal error

Comment: It seems the project uses docker. You may want to look into how you can run a docker project/image.

Answer (score 0):

Just run inside your project / extracted folder

```
composer install / composer update
```